# Принцип работы get set / как менять значение свойства в объекте

Tags: javascript, get, объекты

```
constructor(parentElement) {
this._fa = 0;
this.x = document.createElement('div');
        this.x.className = 'x';
        this.x.innerHTML = `win x: ${this._fa}` //------------------------
        nav.appendChild(this.x);
}
// местами код копировал, по вызовам все номр.
asd() {   for (let i = 0; i < this.winValue.length; i++) {
            this.winValue[i].style.color = 'red';
            if(this.winValue.length==3&& this.winValue[i].innerHTML == "X"){
               this.fa+=1; //------------------------
               console.log(this.fa)
            }
        }

get fa(){
    return this._fa;
}
set fa(value){
    this._fa = value;
}

Хотелось бы менять значение this._fa через get и set, но меняется только в коннсоле, а в самом элементе не спешит меняться...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set fa(value) {
    this._fa = value;
    this.x.innerHTML = `win x: ${this._fa}`;
}
```

Comment: Игорёк ты как всегда на высоте))